# LPR command won't recognize CUPS printer

Tags: linux, cups, lpr

I have a cups server with one shared printer configured on it. It prints test pages without problems.

```
printername (Idle, Accepting Jobs, Shared)
Description:    desc
Location:   
Driver: Zebra ZPL Label Printer (grayscale, 2-sided printing)
Connection: socket://172.20.50.26
Defaults:   job-sheets=none, none media=oe_w288h432_4x6in sides=one-sided
```

This is the output from lpstat -t. it shows that the printer is idle and accepting requests

```
admin@SERVER:~$ lpstat -t
scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for printername: socket://172.20.50.26
printername accepting requests since Thu 26 Jan 2012 01:29:35 PM CET
printer printername is idle.  enabled since Thu 26 Jan 2012 01:29:35 PM CET
```

Now when I want to send a printjob to it via an LPR command it won't recognize the printer

```
/usr/bin/lpr -P printername test.pdf
```

Result

```
lpr: ttn_seg_zebra1: unknown printer
```

What am I missing here
?

Comment: Can you provide the OS details and version (e.g. Red Hat 5.7)?

Comment: Linux version 2.6.9-78.0.8.ELsmp (Red Hat 3.4.6-10))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your printer's name, according to lptstat output is *literally* "printername".

Running `lp -d printername test.pdf` or `lpr -P printername test.pdf` will work.

For example, here's the output from a running system:

```
[root@Smack ~]# lpstat -t
scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for label: socket://label:9100
device for upstairs: socket://upstairs:9100
label accepting requests since Mon Feb 27 05:18:45 2012
upstairs accepting requests since Mon Feb 27 06:31:23 2012
```

In this, I have two printers defined; `label` and `upstairs`. In order to print to them, I'd have to use those names on the lp/lpr command line.

Comment: I edited my original post. The printername is printername in the LPR command.

Comment: lp -d printername test.pdf works indeed. Guess I need to do some reading on the difference between lp,lpr, ....

Comment: So that fixed it? Which OS/distribution are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 11.10

Answer (score 13):

Per comment below:

Install cups-bsd instead of lpr. Cups-bsd contains its own lpr binaries.

This package provides the BSD commands for interacting with CUPS:

```
 /usr/bin/lpqa 
 /usr/bin/lpr 
 /usr/bin/lprm 
 /usr/sbin/lpc
```

Comment: cups-bsd -This package provides the BSD commands for interacting with CUPS: 

/usr/bin/lpqa
/usr/bin/lpr
/usr/bin/lprm
/usr/sbin/lpc

Comment: install: sudo apt-get install cups-bsd